# How to change spelling library in Mac OS X with a shortcut?

Tags: macos, keyboard, preferences, language, spelling

Since I'm a Hungarian, but I learn and work in English, I switch the spelling settings in System Preferences approximately 50 times a day, because I'm constantly working with both languages.

Is there any fast way to change the spelling without opening the System Preferences every single time with a shortcut?

Comment: It might be more helpful if you'd be more explicit and specific about exactly what changes you're making as there may be a way to script it in bash, AppleScript or Automator.  Also what version of OS X are you running?

Comment: You could switch between 2 users...

Comment: Don't you use the Multilingual option in the spell check dialog (Edit » Spelling » Show Spelling & Grammar) ?

Comment: You could make a new service in Automator, make it run an applescript and then going to System Preferences and assigning a shortcut to the Automator service. I am unfortunately on my iPad, so I will provide instructions later on in the day

Comment: @TheBro21: it would be nice to see that

Answer (score 1):

You can set the Language spelling to look for spelling in multiple languages.

My example is English and Spanish.

In the **Keyboard** System preferences go to the **Text** tab.

Set the Spelling dropdown to: **Automatic by Language**

Then opening the **Spelling dropdown** go down to **Set Up…**

[image]

Drag your two (or more) preferred Languages to the top. And then hit the **Done** button.

[image]

Thats it.

Spelling will now recognise the language you are working in.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't think Automatic works with 3rd party dictionaries like Hungarian.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I did not realise it was third party. Should have as  I could not find it on mine. Not sure if it is expected to work with them but this is how you setup spelling for multiple languages..