# How to change the spelling language in OS X with AppleScript?

Tags: macos, applescript, spellcheck, spelling

I often need to change the spelling language in OS X from English to Turkish and vice versa, how can I do it with an AppleScript?

Note: I have read [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/186540/how-to-change-spelling-library-in-mac-os-x-with-a-shortcut) question already, but in there, the answer suggests using Automatic by Language, which does not work properly, so I need to make these specific changes.

I'm using a Mid-2015 MacBook Air with OS X El Capitan 10.11.6.

Comment: I've updated the answer with some info about using it as a AppleScript Application and also how to use it as an Automator Service with a keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **AppleScript** *code*, below, employs **UI Scripting** and because a *popup menu* is involved, **System Preferences** will be made visible (`activate`) during the process. Had a *popup menu* not been involved, this could have been done without making it visible.

That said, technically it still can be done without making the primary window visible, but then all you would see is the *popup menu* flash for a moment on the screen. As this might be more of an annoyance, wondering what just flashed on the screen, showing the whole **System Preferences** window is probably less of an annoyance. You can see the difference and try it by commenting out `activate`, e.g. `-- activate`, and choose which you prefer.

The **AppleScript** *code* does the following:

- Opens **System Preferences** to: **Keyboard** > **Text**
- Changed the language in the **Spelling:** *popup menu* based on the following:

  - If set to **Automatic by Language**, changes it to **U.S. English**.
  - If set to **U.S. English**, changes it to **Türkçe**.
  - If set to **Türkçe**, changes it to **U.S. English**.
- Closes **System Preferences**.

Essentially, once it is not set to **Automatic by Language**, it then toggles between **U.S. English** and **Türkçe**. each time it's run.

You can save this as an **AppleScript** *application*, place it in the **Dock**, then each time it's clicked it will toggle between the two languages. <sub>(Once it's first set to one of the languages.)</sub>

**Note:** Saved an **AppleScript** *application* it will need to be added to  **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** > **Accessibility**, adding the app to the **Allow the apps below to control your computer** list.

This also could be made into an **Automator** *service*, where a *keyboard shortcut* could be assigned. (See the directions at the end of this answer.)

**Note:** The following **AppleScript** *Code* was tested under **OS X El Capitan 10.11.6** and may need to be reworked for use with other versions of **OS X/macOS**.

**AppleScript** *Code*:

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    reveal anchor "Text" of pane id "com.apple.preference.keyboard"
    delay 0.5
    tell application "System Events"
        tell pop up button 3 of tab group 1 of window 1 of application process "System Preferences"
            if (value) is "U.S. English" then
                click
                click menu item "Türkçe" of menu 1
            else if (value) is "Türkçe" then
                click
                click menu item "U.S. English" of menu 1
            else if (value) is "Automatic by Language" then
                click
                click menu item "U.S. English" of menu 1
            end if
        end tell
    end tell
    quit
end tell
```

**Note:** Because **UI Scripting** can sometimes be dependent on the timing of things, the *value* of the `delay` *command* may need to be adjusted and or additional `delay` *commands* may need to be added as/if necessary when run on your system. Make those changes as appropriate.

Also, if you want to make it just always toggle between the two languages, having already set it to one or the other under normal circumstances, you can remove the following lines of *code* from the `if` *statement block* in the *script*:

```
else if (value) is "Automatic by Language" then
    click
    click menu item "U.S. English" of menu 1
```

---

To use this **AppleScript** *code* as an **Automator Service**, do the following:

- In **Automator**, select: **File** > **New** > **Service**
- Set: **Service receives no input** in **any application**
- Add a **Run AppleScript** *Action*.

  - Delete the lines containing `(* Your script goes here *)` and `return input`.
  - Paste in the **AppleScript** *code* within the `on run` *handler*.
- Save the **Automator Service**, giving it an appropriate name, e.g.: **Toggle Spelling Language**

In **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Services** > **(Name You Gave The Service)**, you can *add* the *keyboard shortcut* to *trigger* this service.